# Is there a better way than this to split a string at commas and periods?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

Trying to split a randomly generated string of letters, commas, periods, and spaces at the commas and periods, but I've only figured out how to split it at the commas with this code:

```
import re
    with open('book.txt', 'r') as file_object:
          for line in file_object:
            word_list = list(ast.literal_eval(re.subn(r'(\w+)', r"'\1'", file_object.readline())[0]))
```

example string `s,wgzggarhz hbmk.q.af mnttxvixkcxwheysijneupvkcmmnar.mhvsflinmk,dvoxuce,vb,f.cfb`

End goal is to split it into a list such as `['s', 'wgzggarhz hbmk', 'q', 'af mnttxvixkcxwheysijneupvkcmmnar', 'mhvflinmk', 'dvoxuce', 'vb', 'f', 'cfb']`

I'm new to using RegEx's so I don't know if there's a better way to format this or not, but this is the error it's returning.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
    word_list = list(ast.literal_eval(re.subn(r'(\w+)', r"'\1'", file_object.readline())[0]))
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 59, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    'bazmhffkibauiaexggdoqrvxzkjhqzwammyizcybqba'.'qkmhwbvm' 'cdioyazkwbg' .'bdrsujlrkfxaen'
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Using Replit for IDE

Comment: What do you expect as output for that particular input?

Comment: to split it into a list such as ['s', 'wgzggarhz hbmk', 'q', 'af mnttxvixkcxwheysijneupvkcmmnar', 'mhvflinmk', 'dvoxuce', 'vb', 'f', 'cfb'] will clarify that on post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping words in quotes and then evaluating them again is overkill.

You could use `.split()`:

```
with open('book.txt', 'r') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        word_list = re.split(r'\s*[,.]\s*', line)
        print(word_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Now, if I'm doing this for a text file that's around 15k lines long... it's gonna take a few minutes lol right?

Comment: I guess you don't want to *print* 15k lines. But yes, each line needs to be converted to a list... however you do it, that takes time.

Answer (score 1):

You may just keep it simple and replace all periods with commas (or vice versa) and then use the `.split()` method to get the desired list of strings.

```py
with open('book.txt', 'r') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        word_list = line.replace('.', ',').split(',')
        print(word_list)
```